# fallo nmp de angularx-social-login

Tags: angular, login, npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cuando intento ejecutar el nmp i de angularx-social-login
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me saltan todos estos errores :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi versión de Angular es la 9.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el package.json: {
"name": "celon-dashboard",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"-": "0.0.1",
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
"@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/google-maps": "^11.2.13",
"@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
"@google-cloud/bigquery": "^5.12.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^18.4.48",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
"chart.js": "^2.9.4",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"firebase": "^7.24.0",
"firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.20.1",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"ng-material-treetable": "^0.5.5",
"ng2-charts": "^2.4.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"save": "^2.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.14.1",
"xlsx": "^0.16.9",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1002.4",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.15",
"@angular/cli": "^9.1.15",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
"@angular/language-service": "^9.1.13",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
"@types/node": "^12.20.48",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
"firebase-tools": "^8.20.0",
"fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
"inquirer": "^6.2.2",
"inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.4.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
"open": "^7.4.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.3",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~3.8.3"
}
}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: quiero saber qué comando utilizar, o por qué no me puedo descargar la librería.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se instala un paquete se debe verificar su compatibilidad. En este caso `angularx-social-login` es la versión 4 y requiere angular 12.

Tu proyecto usa Angular 9 así que la versión que debe usarse es la 3:

```
npm i angularx-social-login@3.5.7
```

[Referencia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login#:%7E:text=the%20demo.-,Comatibility%20Matrix,-Library%20Version)

Comment: ya lo probé, he intentado usar estos comandos:
npm install --save angularx-social-login
 npm i angularx-social-login@3.5.4
npm install --save angular-9-social-login
npm i angularx-social-login
 me sigue saliendo error.

Comment: Agrega el error que sale al ejecutar `npm i angularx-social-login@3.5.7`

Comment: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Macarena\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Macarena\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-20T16_45_02_245Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Agrega una captura como la primera donde se vea qué está intentando instalar y cuál es el conflicto. Porque si la versión ya es la correcta solo agrega  —legacy-peer-deps`  al final del comando.

Comment: ya la he añadido, he usado este comando. intento descargarme el angular social login para hacer una autentificación con facebook en una aplicación.